# GNU ld: What is the difference between these two linker scripts?

Tags: linker, gnu, ld

It looks like a game of "spot the difference" for software engineers at first,
but the tiny difference in syntax apparently makes a huge difference in linking behaviour.

ldscript1:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf64-x86-64)
ENTRY(main)
ABS_FIRST = 0x10000000;
OFF_SECOND = 0x20000000;
SECTIONS
{
    . = ABS_FIRST;
    .first :
    {
        *(.pre)
    }
    . += OFF_SECOND;
    .text :
    {
        *(.text)
        *(.rodata*)
    }
    .data :
    {
        *(.data)
    }
}
```

ldscript2:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf64-x86-64)
ENTRY(main)
ABS_FIRST = 0x10000000;
OFF_SECOND = 0x20000000;
SECTIONS
{
    . = ABS_FIRST;
    .first :
    {
        *(.pre)
    }
    hack = .;
    . = hack + OFF_SECOND;
    .text :
    {
        *(.text)
        *(.rodata*)
    }
    .data :
    {
        *(.data)
    }
}
```

pre.s:

```
.section .pre
.long 0x0
```

main.c:

```
int main()
{
}
```

compiled and linked with:

```
gcc -c -xassembler-with-cpp -o pre.o pre.s
gcc -c -o main.o main.c
ld -T ldscriptX pre.o main.o -o example
```

ld version:

```
$ ld -v
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.22
```

With ldscript1:

```
$ objdump -h example | grep -E ".text|VMA"
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  2 .text         00000006  0000000020000000  0000000020000000  00200000  2**2
```

With ldscript2:

```
$ objdump -h example | grep -E ".text|VMA"
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  2 .text         00000006  0000000030000004  0000000030000004  00200004  2**2
```

Note that the VMA is correct for ldscript2, but somehow "." got set back to zero before/in the "+=" operation in ldscript1.  I have read the GNU ld documentation, but cannot find an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like ldscript1 behaves as expected...

This looks like a relative/absolute address issue. What is the value assigned to hack?  I suspect it is 0.

Can you try `hack = ABSOLUTE(.) ;` ?